# dynamic plugin redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I use redux-form with conjuction of redux-dynamic-modules. So my state's shape dynamically changes when different components mounts/unmounts. My app contains 2 forms one of which loads dynamically. My root module contains formReducer from redux-form. What I want to do is to add dynamicFormReducer (plugin) to formReducer only when dynamic form loaded. When I set plugin in root module it works (and this is understandable).

https://codesandbox.io/s/k10m98w683

Comment: I've partially solved the problem specifying separate form reducers for each module and passing getFormState function to reduxForm decorator. But. Now "dynamicForm"  key present in both forms of "root" and "dynamic" parts of the state. I don't know actually is it acceptable to have several form reducers in one redux store?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/o99286qmm9